# A characterization of Moishezon manifolds via sections of $L^k$ with $k\to \infty$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth compact complex manifold of dimension $n$. Suppose $L$ is a line bundle on $X$ such that $dim(H^0(X,L^k))>c\cdot k^n$ for $c>0$ and $k>>0$.

**Question.** Is it true that $X$ is Moishezon? Is there some reference for this statement?

Comment: do you mean $k^n$?

Comment: The question correspond to volume of line bundle. $L$ is big,  implies the
projectivity of X is  Moishezon. Note that $L$ is big iff $Vol(L)>0$. By definition $$Vol(L)=\lim sup_{p\to\infty}\frac{n!}{p^n}dim H^0(X,L^p)$$

Comment: You may see 2.2.15 of the following charpter: https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~xiaonan.ma/M2_17/Moishezon.pdf

Comment: @ChenJiang: why not turn your good comment into an answer? That will be helpful for future visitors, prevent against link-rot, etc.